# What does this git log refs mean?

Tags: git

> Create a migration file to add the coupon_id column to the orders table. refs #12195 #13158

I saw a git log message like the above, but I don't know the meaning of this the refs #12195.
thanks for answering.

Comment: Isn't the commit message entered by user ? Um...

Comment: Ask the person in charge of the git repository what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tool like [unfuddle](https://unfuddle.com/) (which does include a bug tracking) do mention in its doc "[Powerful Commit Messages](https://unfuddle.com/support/docs/topics/powerful-commit-messages)"

> Unfuddle allows you to manipulate the status of tickets within your projects directly from your repository commit messages.
>
> - **`addresses`** (references, refs, re, see) will associate the Git commit with the specified tickets noting that the ticket was affected by the commit in some way.

```
     git commit -am 'refs #124, #125 and #129 and closes #126'
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably it references bugs number 12195 and 13158 in a bug tracker somewhere.